# How do I boot from a partition on my external HDD

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, external-hard-drive, kali-linux

I partitioned my 1TB external HDD into 4 parts. I use one to store files. I booted Kali Linux from my 16gb usb stick and installed kali on one of my external HDD partitions. The installation was successful but I cannot boot my PC from that partition of my external HDD; if i boot from usb, it skips and loads windows from my internal HDD. How do i boot from a that partition of my external HDD where kali is installed.

Comment: UEFI or Legacy?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've got Windows 10 on a current computer.

- Boot to Windows.
- Restart it, pressing shift when you issue the restart command and keep it pressed until a blue screen with further options show up.
- Choose Use a Device, and your kali install should appear as a UEFI option.

Comment: No. I've got windows 7

Comment: Is your computer old enough for you to easily get into the BIOS? You should be able to pick boot options from there.

Comment: Yes I can pick boot options to boot from USB but not from a partition of that USB device

Comment: Then, maybe you should boot from a linux pendrive and use it to install a boot manager